# Why my SQL query does not apply my where not equal condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I used a CTE (temp table) to compute data through semesters. With my query, I want to compare if my data (already aggregated) are equal to my sum computed in my CTE. However, when using `WHERE data_already_aggregated <> data_computed`  I got a result where my results in those columns are equal. I tried to use =! as well, and also =. Last option worked, but not the way I want.

Here my code:

```
WITH trimestriel AS(
SELECT "donnéestrim".annee,
       "donnéestrim".trimestre,
       "donnéestrim".codescpi,
       scpi.scpi,
       "donnéestrim"."rd_t",
       SUM("donnéestrim".rd_t) OVER (PARTITION BY "donnéestrim".annee, "donnéestrim".codescpi) AS "trim_sum_totalYear_rd_t",
       row_number() over (partition BY scpi.codescpi, annee) AS "row_number"
FROM "donnéestrim"
LEFT JOIN scpi ON scpi.codescpi = "donnéestrim".codescpi
ORDER BY "donnéestrim".annee)

SELECT "annuel".codescpi,
       scpi.scpi ,
       "annuel".annee,
       trimestriel."trimestre",
       "annuel".revdisavpl AS "annuel_revdisavpl",
       "trim_sum_totalYear_rd_t",
       "rd_t" AS "trim_rd_t"
FROM "annuel"
LEFT JOIN scpi ON scpi.codescpi = "annuel".codescpi
LEFT JOIN trimestriel ON trimestriel.codescpi = "annuel".codescpi AND trimestriel.annee=annuel.annee
WHERE    "annuel".annee = '2018' and scpi.codescpi = '129' and "annuel".revdisavpl != "trim_sum_totalYear_rd_t"
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HatSf.png)

Comment: What is the data type of `"annuel".revdisavpl` and `"donnéestrim".rd_t`? I'm wondering if this is a floating point rounding thing.

Comment: Also, *where* do you add that additional condition?

Comment: @JNevill "annuel".revdisavpl and "donnéestrim".rd_t are double precision type. I thoughtabout that too.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe On my last line.

Comment: When I do `"annuel".revdisavpl::text NOT LIKE "trim_sum_totalYear_rd_t"::text` everythink worked as expected. This is an unelrgant solution and I am really not satisfied with it.

Comment: You don't tell us which tables the columns belong to, and I still have no idea what your query is. Please post the complete problematic query and its execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JNevill suggested, it's a data type problem. A double precision type only display the data with its specific parameters, but can store more information if casted. I cast it to real, and I can saw the gaps between my data.